# Android studio builds all bundles with the same key

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

When I try to build my app's bundle to a release, Android studio builds the app with a different Signing key, What is happening that I'm choosing the key i signed app to in play store and build the bundle, when I try to upload the bundle as an update to my app in play store, play store refuses the bundle and give me error :

> Upload failed
>
> Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your
>   App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again: SHA1:
>   ***:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**.

Notice: I chose the right signing key, But the bundle is being built with a different one.
I tried to re Install android studio

Answer (score 0):

try to reset your android studio

I only know how to do this on Windows (but it should be similar on any OS, you will just need to find the correct location yourself - google search would help with that).

On Windows:

Go to your User Folder -

[SYSDRIVE]:\Users[your username] (ex. C:\Users\JohnDoe)

In this folder, there should be a folder called.AndroidStudioBeta or.AndroidStudio (notice the period at the start - so on some OSes, it would be hidden).

Delete this folder (or better yet, move it to a backup location - so you can return it if something goes wrong).

This should reset your Android Studio settings to default.